# What points on the unit circle sum to $a\in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, reference-request, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Write the unit-norm complex numbers as $U$, fix $n\in\mathbb{N},\ a\in\mathbb{C}$, and $S\! :=\! \left\lbrace z\in U^n\! : \textstyle\sum_1^n z_i = a\right\rbrace \subset \mathbb{C}^n.$
In general, what formula maps an uncomplicated domain into (at least most of) $S$?

Comment: Is $S$ guaranteed to be bounded ?

Comment: Since its a subset of $U^n$ it is bounded.

Comment: It's a problem statement question, @Christian.  Please read the Enforcement of Quality Standards, which applies also to answerers of very low quality questions.

Comment: I think I've done a pretty good job of paring this question down to the basics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is straightforward but does not admit a convenient declarative description.

Notice that for $n=2$ and $a$ with $|a|\in(0,2]$ the choice of $z_1,z_2$ is essentially unique:
\begin{equation}
    z_1=\frac{a}{2}\left[1+i\sqrt{4|a|^{-2}-1}\right],\quad z_2=z_1'.
\end{equation}
Define $\phi:2B\backslash \{0\}\to U^2$ to be the map $a\mapsto (z_1,z_2).$

Now any $z=(z_t)_t\in S$ is an outcome of the following construction up to permutation of indices:

- If $n$ is odd, fix $n'=n-1$ and choose $z_0\in U$ so that $|a-z_0|\leq n'.$ Also say $w_0:=z_0.$ Otherwise fix $n'=n.$
- For $k$ starting from $1$ and through $n'/2$:

  - Choose $w_k$ so that $|a-\sum_{t\leq k} w_t|\leq n'
    -2k.$
  - If $w_k=0$ then choose arbitrary $u\in U$ and define $(z_{2k-1},z_{2k})=(u,-u)$. Otherwise define $(z_{2k-1},z_{2k})=\phi(w_k)$.

Comment: Of course, $S$ is empty if $\lvert a\rvert>n$, this is probably obvious from your answer but I can't see it explicitly written, hence my comment.